# Rails 5: (No route matches [HEAD] "assets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to develop a new web application. I never had this problem before, but somehow it appeard today.

```
(No route matches [HEAD] "assets"/assets/top3-6b91882a0de709cbd323b847ba6c8c8207b6a652aa75174a2d61a5b41ae1e71c@2x.jpg")
```

So the image is in my assets/images folder, but the file name is top3.jpg.
And now it is for every image and the load time is imense, but the images are still showing up on my page.

I don't know where the random numbers and letters come from. I'm in development mode.

#### EDIT

So I turned off the fingerprint and I'm still getting an error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/assets/logo-black@2x.png"):
```

I'm wondering where @2x come from ?

Comment: Do you have retina.js somewhere in your project?

Comment: @PavelOganesyan No

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for the rails asset pipeline https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

The technique is called **Fingerprinting**

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.

Comment: I turned off the fingerpringt, but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Do you have this setting on config/environments/development.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true